# passing a string to assign a integer to a variable why isnt this code working?

Tags: php

The string im trying to pass is "www.he2media.com/index.php?mobile=false" what am I doing wrong?

```
<?PHP

require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

$ismobiledevice;
if($_GET['mobile']=== "")
{
   $ismobiledevice=0;
}
if($_GET['mobile']==="false")
{
  $ismobiledevice=1;
}
if($detect->isMobile()&& empty($ismobiledevice))
{
  header("Location:http://m.he2media.com");
}
else
{
  header("Location:http://www.he2media.com");
}
?>
```

Comment: `www.he2media.com/index.php?mobile=false` is this the url that loads above script?

Comment: Can you tell what is the logic, why `""` and `false`, are these different ?

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 Because `(string) "false" == true`.

Comment: I didn't ask it, I asked what is `OP` trying to accomplish on what condition ?

Comment: What do you mean by not working actually?

Comment: What problem are you facing actually ? Is it redirecting to the wrong page, or it isn't redirecting at all ? Or anything else... ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually passing a string, you are setting a header location.

Perhaps you should add a space between `Location:` and the URL:

```
header("Location: http://...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` is doing opposite of what it should do

```
 if($_GET['mobile']=== ""){
     $ismobiledevice=0;}
 if($_GET['mobile']==="false"){
     $ismobiledevice=1;}
```

That means if the url says `mobile==false`, still go to the mobile version.
You can simply join the two if statements properly like:

```
  if($detect->isMobile()&& $_GET['mobile']!="false"){      
      header("Location:http://m.he2media.com");
  }else{
      header("Location:http://www.he2media.com");
  }
```